# Would "modern ways of alcohol concealment" be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, specific-question

I would like to ask a question(s) on the modern ways people use to conceal alcohol ([bootlegging](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bootlegging)) on their person, but would like your input as to whether or not it would be considered on topic on the main site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [on-topic](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page:

> Topics include, but are not limited to:
>
> - Specific beers, wines, liquors, ciders, or other alcoholic drinks
> - Breweries, wineries, and distilleries
> - Alcohol & production history
> - Styles & ingredients
> - Cultural and geographic questions specifically related to alcohol

So this feels off topic to me.

If you actually do wish to know, google will show you pictures of all the common ones:-)